# Does sentimentr package account for number of words in sentence and number of sentence in paragraph?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, lexicon, sentimentr

Can anyone help explain whether sentimentr package accounts for word number? I am trying to work out how the number of words affects the sentiment score. Does it take into account if people have more sentences in an answer or more words per sentence? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sentimentr does account for the number of words. This is from the documentation:

The researcher may provide a weight z to be utilized with amplifiers/de-amplifiers (default is .8; de-amplifier weight is constrained to -1 lower bound). Last, these weighted context clusters (c_i,j,l) are summed (c'_i,j) and divided by the square root of the word count (√n w_i,jn) yielding an unbounded polarity score (C) for each sentence.